# Are different Heroku installations conflicting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have spent many hours trying to understand the implications of local installation vs global (root?) installation, but couldn't grasp enough to even formulate a question. This issue (below) with Heroku is a part of that puzzle.

Heroku had been installed-and worked with some simple rails apps. But out of the blue, I began to get an error message that I should install Heroku CLI. Thinking perhaps I had messed things up, I went ahead and used Brew to install Heroku this time (`brew install heroku/brew/heroku`) Though the installation was successful, I continued to get the same error message about installing Heroku CLI.

Today, I started another rails app (`rails new MyApp`, got the same error message `Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com`, tried `brew install heroku/brew/heroku` yet again, and here's a new message:

```
Warning: heroku/brew/heroku 7.7.8 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link heroku` to link this version.
```

When I did `brew link heroku` , I got this:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/heroku
Target /usr/local/bin/heroku
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/heroku'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite heroku

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run heroku
```

and `brew link --overwrite --dry-run heroku` led to:

```
Would remove:
/usr/local/bin/heroku -> /usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku
```

1. Am I correct to assume that I am dealing with conflicting installations?
2. How do I resolve the current Heroku issue--let it remove duplicate files? What does that mean? (And which gets removed: `/usr/local/bin/heroku` or `/usr/local/lib/heroku/bin/heroku` ?
3. I believe I have similar issues related to ruby gem installations. I'd appreciate some pointers on understanding the fundamental issue of global vs local (vs individual app installations?), specifically related to ruby, rails and ruby gems.

Comment: A symbolic link is just a "pointer", not the files themselves. It is basically a redirect when it is referenced. "overwriting" is just overwriting the symbolic link, not the installation. Yours doesn't appear to have any type of conflict of "global vs individual", based on what I can see from your output. I am not an OSX user,only Linux, but permissions does not appear to be the issue at all.

Comment: Thank you, @ForeverZer0 and a follow-up question: In this case, the "conflict" really is a matter of referencing--that may explain a lot of my issues. Is there a way to minimize such issues, so that starting an app doesn't involve adjusting the pointer (and leading to other apps having the same issues)?

Comment: I would uninstall any brew versions of Heroku and install via the downloader https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

Comment: @Schneems: I sorta solved the problem by removing rbenv and ruby NOT installed by brew (at least I think that's what happened). But now I get "Do you want Ruby to accept incoming connections" each time I start rails server. Aside from just getting rails and heroku to run, I really want to understand the best practice of installing ruby/rails vis a vis local/global installation, but I don't know enough to post the right question at the moment.