# Heroku installs disconnected--asking for Heroku CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Need help-fixing the problem (and understanding it). I have uninstalled and re-installed Heroku, Brew, and rbenv many times, yet Heroku still refuses to see itself. Below are the main steps I have taken to try to fix it:

```
$ which heroku
 /Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/shims/heroku
```

Yet:

```
$ heroku version
Traceback (most recent call last):
 2: from /Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
 1: from /Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem heroku (>= 0.a) with executable heroku (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Since the Heroku gem is not installed:

```
$ gem list heroku
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

I installed it:

```
$ gem install heroku
Fetching: heroku-3.99.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed heroku-3.99.3
Parsing documentation for heroku-3.99.3
Installing ri documentation for heroku-3.99.3
Done installing documentation for heroku after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Check Heroku's version:

```
$ which heroku
/Users/my-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/heroku
```

Looks good. Yet:

```
$ heroku open
Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
```

What is going on here?
I did a search (following a tip) and found these with 'Heroku' in the file name:

```
$ sudo find / -type d -name "*heroku*"

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku
/usr/local/lib/heroku
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-ps-exec/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/heroku-exec-util
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/heroku-exec-util/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/heroku-client
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/@heroku
/usr/local/lib/heroku/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/@heroku-cli
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-ps-exec/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/heroku-exec-util
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/heroku-exec-util/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/heroku-client
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/@heroku
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku/7.7.8/libexec/node_modules/heroku-cli-util
...
/Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/doc/heroku-3.99.3
/Users/my-mbp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/heroku-3.99.3
/Users/my-mbp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/doc/heroku-3.99.3
/Users/my-mbp/Library/Logs/Homebrew/heroku
/Users/my-mbp/Library/Logs/Homebrew/heroku-node
/Users/my-mbp/railsapps/myapp/.git/logs/refs/remotes/heroku
/Users/my-mbp/railsapps/myapp/.git/refs/remotes/heroku
/Users/my-mbp/railsapps/toy_app/.git/logs/refs/remotes/heroku
/Users/my-mbp/railsapps/toy_app/.git/refs/remotes/heroku
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

Previously I have asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804851/are-different-heroku-installations-conflicting), got a good tip on the problem. Unfortunately I wasn't able to bring up the same error message again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [heroku gem is deprecated](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb). You should [install the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) using homebrew instead:

```
brew install heroku/brew/heroku
```

If it is already installed, just upgrade it:

```
brew upgrade heroku/brew/heroku
```

Remember to restart your terminal after installation.

Also, please let me know if it works for you so I can update my answer.

Comment: Updating didn't work: `$ brew upgrade heroku/brew/heroku
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
automake ✔          bdw-gc              di                  fselect
Error: heroku/brew/heroku 7.7.8 already installed`

Comment: Does the download not work for you? It has a GUI installer https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli. Based on that error you should first try to uninstall the old version of `heroku` from homebrew.